# ¿Cómo puedo aprender desarrollo web con visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net

me considero una principiante en programación y anteriormente sólo he utilizado visual studio para aplicaciones de escritorio pero me encantaría aprender a usarlo para desarrollo web. Me metí a indagar en los cursos gratuitos que tiene microsoft learn sobre ASP.net y net, pero el problema es que siento que está un poco desordenado, no sé por dónde empezar y en uno de los minicursos mesclaron visual code con visual studio lo que me confundió un poco, la verdad ando muy pérdida. Entonces... ¿Alguien sabe algún curso gratuito o por dónde podría empezar para aprender a utilizar ASP.net y net?, aunque aun tengo muy claro la diferencia...Realmente me gustaría aprender aprender a programar páginas web y aprender sobre webservices.
De antemano gracias por la ayuda y por favor no cierren mi pregunta, realmente quiero aprender a programar!

Comment: La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de cursos, libros, etc por lo que terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira te recomiendo el siguiente curso para aprender un poco de la estructura de .Net y Angular [ASPNET Core and Angular](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-an-app-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-from-scratch/), aqui aprenderas un poco de bases de datos, cambios de contexto y un poco de versionado.
También te recomiendo que siempre consultes la documentación oficial de microsoft [Overview of ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0), al principio parece que esta revuelta, pero la cosa es que está separado por temas y dentro de cada tema tiene sus subtemas, no lo veas como una guía que va en secuencia , sino en diferentes secciones.
También te recomiendo el siguiente curso para que te vayas metiendo un poco al front [Angular Fernando Herrera](https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-2-fernando-herrera/learn/lecture/9384168?start=0#overview).
Por último, para que conozca mas de base de datos y cambios de contexto, te recomiendo la siguiente página [Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx) que te dará un panorama más abierto en dependencias, que es un framework para backend, transacciones, etc.

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Y no olvides también buscar algún proveedor de nube, ya sea AWS, Azure, IBM cloud, Google Cloud,pero también está para hacer hosting digitalOcean y heroku. Seria cosa que buscaras los pros y contras de cada uno y se adapte a tus necesidades.

Suerte.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones o buscando recomendaciones es mejor evitar responderlas pues no se ajustan a [ask] y terminan cerradas, puedes dejarle en su lugar comentarios :)

Comment: Gracias Jaime, me has ayudado mucho!